# Can't start MongoDB, mongod is always stop/waiting

Tags: 14.04, permissions, services, mongodb

I try to run `MongoDB` 3.2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

And get the result:

```
mongod start/running, process 67725
```

But when I check the status I get:

```
mongod stop/waiting
```

I tried to reinstall `MongoDB` or to define the permissions for Mongo's folders (`lib` & `log`) as `root` or as `mongodb`. I also tried to repair the `mongod.conf` but nothing helps.

The content of log:

```
2016-04-09T23:56:28.349+0300 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2016-04-09T23:56:28.359+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=69120 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=is-infomedia
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.4
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-04-09T23:56:28.360+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-04-09T23:56:28.393+0300 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
2016-04-09T23:56:28.393+0300 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2016-04-09T23:56:28.393+0300 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

**Update:**

After editing of `/etc/mongod.conf`:

```
#security:
authorization: enabled
enableEncryption: true
javascriptEnabled: false
```

and saving the file, and try to restart the `mongod`, I get the same error but MongoDB doesn't write any log file. I checked the permissions of `/etc/mongod.conf`, it is assigned to `mongodb` group. How can I restart `mongod` after editing its config file?

**My questions:**

1. How can I run `MongoDB` as a service in Ubuntu?
2. What I miss or do wrong?

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable servicename` - to run it as service. This issue looks like problems with premissions, try sudo chown ```whoami``` /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock to get premissions straight. If that wont help, can You remove the socket?

Comment: @Eska, bingo! The `sudo chown mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` fixed the issue. Please, arrange your comment as an answer in order to mark it as correct.

Comment: Uncomment ```#security:```, it should be
 ```security:
           authorization: "enabled"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like premissions issue, please do:

```
sudo chown whoami /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

This will set premissions straight as You need.

Comment: One more moment, I just edited `/etc/mongod.conf` (added `#security: authorization: enabled enableEncryption: true javascriptEnabled: false`) saved the file, and tried to restart `mongod` and get the same error but MongoDB doesn't write any log file. I checked, the permissions, `/etc/mongod.conf` assigned to `mongodb` group. How can I restart `mongod` after editing its config file?

Comment: You reset service by `sudo systemctl restart servicename`. If You want to check mongo status, do `sudo systemctl status servicename`.

Comment: If You will hit `tab` after typing `sudo systemctl` You will get list of available commands for `systemctl`

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that this package is not installed and in order to use it I have to reboot the system, which is not possible due to already running programs.

Comment: Please try `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, maybe that will do to avoid reboot.

Comment: On the other hand, if system requires to restart for the proper run of the app, i wouldn't recommend to try to avoid/bypass this action. May i ask whats the machine duty? (I mean, is it some kind of server machine connected to production process in facility or something like that?)

Comment: It's a local workstation, which is used by multiple persons and, thus, it's problematical to restart the system.

Comment: I don't think there is a safe way to achieve what You need. I may be mistaken, but if linux need a reboot for something, that actually probably means something bigger than just a reload of the config files. I was installing php7-fpm, mariadb, nginx all together 2 days ago on Debian Stretch - there was no need to reboot to get them working straight away as systemctl services.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change permission of the whole `mongodb` folder in `/var/lib/`. Gave it all permissions read and write and now my service starts.

[image]